# C++: Could setsockopt() be ignored by a signal?

Tags: c++, xml, tcp, signals, recv

I am working with a code that uses XML over TCP communication. This implementation has a 10 seconds timeout for each `send()` and `recv()` to wait for the whole data using `setsockopt()` . After sometime working I found that sometimes `recv()` doesn't wait for the timeout and returned a -1 value. While I was trying to solve the problem I added a `sleep(2)` in the code and I found out that the `sleep()` was interrupted every time I encountered the recv error. Based on this I think the root of the problem is a signal, but I've failed to find which signal is.

My question is the following: Could recv()'s wait be interrupted by a signal? Note: `recv()`'s wait is set at `setsockopt()`

EDIT:
Here is the solution (Thanks for the help):

```
while (buf > 0)
{
  rsize = recv(socket, bufsize, buf, 0)
  if (rsize == -1)
  {
    if (errno == EINTR)
      continue;
    break;
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: What do you actually mean _ignored by a signal_?? Signals are processed asynchronously, and may be processed independently of waiting code in different threads.

Comment: Your _signal aware_  `recv()` is blatant nonsensical code BTW.

Comment: Yes, I am working in Linux. I meant if recv() could be interrupted by a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux (and UNIX in general), a call to `recv()` can be interrupted by delivery of a signal.

> [EINTR]
>   The `recv()` function was interrupted by a signal that was caught, before any data was available.
>   <sub>[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html)</sub>

If you encounter `EINTR` or detect a shorter than expected message size, simply restart your `recv()` (adjusted for however many bytes have been read so far).

If you use `sigaction()` to establish your signal handler, you can set the `SA_RESTART` flag to allow system calls to be automatically restarted after the signal handler is called. `recv()` is one of the calls that will be restarted under Linux (details found with [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Comment: Is there is way to handle that signal so it doesn't interrupt my recv()?

Comment: @EdRivera Just set the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction` when setting up the signal handler. This will cause interrupted syscalls to be restarted automatically (with a few exceptions). See `signal(7)` for more info.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: Ah, thanks for that input. SA_RESTART behavior is slightly different system to system, but seems to be an excellent choice for Linux.

Comment: @jxh Yes, it may have slightly different semantics on other UNIX variants, but usually it's not a concern. If this is a problem, then you have to explicitly do the restart manually when `recv(2)` fails with `EINTR`.

Comment: Since any signal may cause an interruption, you would have to cath all of them. Or simply write a wrapper around `recv()` to restart it yourself.